# Docker, is it possible copy host's data to docker volume?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

Currently I am using host's directory as a mounting point(?) for elasticsearch data (/var/lib/elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data)

```
 version: '3'

 services:
  elasticsearch:
   build:
     context: .
     dockerfile: ./compose/elasticsearch/Dockerfile
     args:
       - VERSION=${VERSION}
       - ELASTICSEARCH_PORT=${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT}
       - MEM=${MEM}
       - CLUSTER_NAME=${CLUSTER_NAME}
       - ENV=${ENV}
   container_name: elasticsearch
   network_mode: host
   environment:
     - discovery.type=single-node
   volumes:
    - /var/lib/elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

I want to use docker's volume as following.

Is it possible to move the data in `/var/lib/elasticsearch` to `data:` ?

```
 services:
  elasticsearch:
   build:
     context: .
     dockerfile: ./compose/elasticsearch/Dockerfile
     args:
       - VERSION=${VERSION}
       - ELASTICSEARCH_PORT=${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT}
       - MEM=${MEM}
       - CLUSTER_NAME=${CLUSTER_NAME}
       - ENV=${ENV}
   container_name: elasticsearch
   network_mode: host
   environment:
     - discovery.type=single-node
   volumes:
     - data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data

  volumes:
    data:
```

Comment: if you do `docker volume inspect data` it should tell the Mountpoint in your host, then just `mv /var/lib/elasticsearch/* <mountpoint>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `docker cp` command to copy the files from host machine once the new container is created which mounts the `data` volume.

`docker cp /var/lib/elasticsearch/. elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/`

You can also create a dummy container before starting the elasticsearch container in case you want to data to be present before starting the elasticsearch container. This will not work if you are using docker-compose to start elasticsearch as docker-compose namespaces the volumes by pre-pending the project name.

```
docker container create --name dummy -v data:/root hello-world
docker cp /var/lib/elasticsearch/. dummy:/root/`
docker rm dummy
```

Comment: very informative, 

just to be sure, `data` in `data:/root`  matches `volumes:
    data:` in the docker-compose file? and `/root` is there just for copying?

Comment: Looks like docker-compose name spaces the volumes and so the data volume from the dummy container approach would be different from the data volume created by docker-compose.


https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3115


The first approach of copying after starting the elastic search using docker-compose should work. You can just restart the elasticsearch using docker-compose restart